# Getting radio button after the text in windows phone 8 application

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, radio-button

how do i a align radio button to the right and the text to the left ??
Currently i am using FlowDirection="RightToLeft" and then setting HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"

this is giving me the desired output , but if the string length is very big , it starts to trim content from the left margin , i would prefer the trimmed content from the right margin

Comment: Do you know how tu use blend? You can open the file where the control is in Blend, and then you edit a copy of the control template. Then you can edit that part of the control.

Comment: thanks @AndréMeneses , but i managed to get it work by setting it's setter value in xaml

Comment: An option could be to use a separate label for the text and a radio button along with it with no text.